# getting microseconds become zero in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use 'diff()' to get the difference of two consecutive time data in microseconds.

But for some data, when the difference is 1 second. I got some problems, which are shown in the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2019-06-10 16:37:16.319', '2019-06-10 16:37:17.319']})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['delta'] = df['time'].diff().dt.microseconds
print(df)
```

the result is 0

When I use

```
df['delta'] = df['time'].diff().dt.seconds
```

The result becomes 1

Comment: as for me all is correct. Difference is 1 second and 0 microseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nuance. The [Timestamp attributes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html#attributes) "access various components of the Timedelta or TimedeltaIndex", they do not convert to that specific frequency. The attributes are defined up to the next unit, so for instance `Timestamp.dt.microseconds` is only defined for microseconds >= 0 and < 1 second.

In your above example, the time difference is exactly 1 second, so there is no microseconds component.

To get the time difference in microseconds use `.dt.total_seconds` and multiply by the conversion.

```
df['delta'] = df['time'].diff().dt.total_seconds()*10**6

                     time      delta
0 2019-06-10 16:37:16.319        NaN
1 2019-06-10 16:37:17.319  1000000.0
```

Comment: Great answer. They can also look at `.dt.components` for a visual aid to grasp your point